# grunt js installing packages

Tags: npm, gruntjs

I'm building a grunt javascript project with grunt, and I have a package.json file that looks something like:

```
{
   ... name, author, etc here ...

   "dependencies": {
      "grunt-html":"0.2.1"
   }

 }
```

I can run `npm install` to install grunt-html and this works just fine. But when I add new dependencies, all developers on the team must know to run `npm install` again. Is there a way to automatically install any packages that have not yet been installed? Should I just run npm install always to ensure I'm up to date?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes `npm install` is the easiest way IMO. Getting everyone familiar with the other `npm` commands makes managing deps easier as well. Such as:

- `npm ls` to list out the currently installed modules.
- Or the `--save` flag ie, `npm install grunt-html --save` to install and insert the package and version into your `package.json`.
- `npm prune` to remove modules not included in your `package.json`.

Other ways to manage dependencies are to commit the `node_modules` folder in your repository to avoid other devs from having to run `npm install`. Or for more complex projects consider using `npm shrinkwrap` to lock down dependencies to specific versions: [npm shrinkwrap docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/shrinkwrap.html).

Comment: It seems like it might be a good idea to commit node_modules for just this reason. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: I use one of the three methods depending on the project. Mostly `npm install` as I'm on a small team. Committing `node_modules` is a good if you don't keep close tabs on the deps as it could help prevent a broken site on deployment. Each method has their pros/cons depending on the project.

Comment: Is there a way I can "save" to `package.json` already installed packages (if haven't been running `npm install` with `--save` flag before)?

Comment: Yes. I believe you can do `npm init` which will either create a new `package.json` or merge with an existing `package.json` file. Including any installed packages.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried grunt-install-dependencies (https://github.com/ahutchings/grunt-install-dependencies), but it seems this may fullfill your needs. Just add the command install-dependencies as first task within your custom definfed grunt tasts, e.g.

grunt.registerTask('build', [ 'install-dependencies', 'useminPrepare', ... ]);